How to dismiss file input dialog in Playwright test when using setInputFiles
I'm working on a Playwright test where I need to interact with a file input dialog. I'm using the setInputFiles function to set the input file, but I'm encountering an issue where the file input dialog pops up and I can't seem to dismiss it. This is causing my test to hang because the dialog remains open.
Here's the relevant part of my test code:
await page.getByTestId('upload-button').click();

const filePath= path.join(__dirname, "rootPath", "secPath", "package.nupkg");
await page.browseInputField.isVisible();
await page.browseInputField.setInputFiles(filePath);

When this line executes, I see the file input dialog appear, but there's no clear way to close it. The DOM only contains a single line for the file input element:
<input id="browseFileInput" data-testid="browseFileInput" class="browseFileInput" type="file" accept=".nupkg">

There are no other buttons or elements that I can interact with to close the dialog.
I'm looking for a solution that allows me to set the input file without the dialog popping up, or if it does pop up, a way to programmatically close it so that the test can continue.
**Minimal Reproducible Example **
Please create a file named test_page.html with the following content:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page for File Input</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="browseFileInput" data-testid="browseFileInput" class="browseFileInput" type="file" accept=".nupkg">
    <button id="upload-button" data-testid="upload-button">Upload</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('upload-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('browseFileInput').click();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

And the Playwright test script that demonstrates the issue:
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const path = require('path');

(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('file:///path/to/test_page.html');

    await page.click('[data-testid="upload-button"]');

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "rootPath", "secPath", "package.nupkg");
    await page.setInputFiles('[data-testid="browseFileInput"]', filePath);

    // Here comes the question - how I close the opened browse dialog?
})();


where the file input dialog pops up and I can't seem to dismiss it Do you know what opens the popup?  The setInputFiles shouldn't open the dialog.

@hardkoded There is an upload button that I click on. Without clicking it, there will be no browseinputfile in the dom as browse dialog isn't popped out. I attached the code, please see updated.

This is missing a [mcve].

@hardkoded Is there a way to set the input files without making the dialog pops out?

Are you sure there is no input file before you click on the button? It will be hard to solve if there is no element there. You can't cancel the file upload programmatically.

I also had this problem and I've decided not to use "setInputFiles" method.
I suggest to do it like this:
const uploadFile = path.resolve(
      __dirname,
      '../yourPathToTheFile'
    )

const uploadPromise = page.waitForEvent('filechooser')
await page.click('[data-testid="upload-button"]')
const fileChooser = await uploadPromise
await fileChooser.setFiles(uploadFile)

If you use debug you will see that filechooser popup is not visible.
